# Energia WiFiUdpSendReceiveString Example Adding Characters to Message - CC3200

Tags: udp

I'm doing some development on the CC3200 LaunchPad by TI using Code Composer Studio v6.1 using Energia 15. I'm successfully running the WiFiUdpSendReceiveString example on my CC3200 but I'm getting some strange behavior when I'm sending a message from the client.

Here is the code on my CC3200

```
#ifndef __CC3200R1M1RGC__
// Do not include SPI for CC3200 LaunchPad
#include <SPI.h>
#endif
#include <WiFi.h>

// your network name also called SSID
char ssid[] = "xxxxx";
// your network password
char password[] = "xxxxxxx";

unsigned int localPort = 2390;      // local port to listen on

char packetBuffer[255]; //buffer to hold incoming packet
char  ReplyBuffer[] = "acknowledged";       // a string to send back

WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup() {

  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);

//  WiFi.deleteProfileSmartConfig();

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
  // print the network name (SSID);
  Serial.println(ssid); 
  // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    // print dots while we wait to connect
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  }

  Serial.println("\nYou're connected to the network");
  Serial.println("Waiting for an ip address");

  while (WiFi.localIP() == INADDR_NONE) {
    // print dots while we wait for an ip addresss
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }

  Serial.println("\nIP Address obtained");
  printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println("\nWaiting for a connection from a client...");
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {

  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize)
  {
    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    IPAddress remoteIp = Udp.remoteIP();
    Serial.print(remoteIp);
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 255);

    if (len > 0) packetBuffer[len] = 0;
    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    // send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(ReplyBuffer);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

I'm using my Macbook terminal as the client to send a message via UDP and I've sent a series of commands to show the UDP issue:

```
echo -n "CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411" | nc -4u -w1 192.168.1.57 2390
echo -n "CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764" | nc -4u -w1 192.168.1.57 2390
echo -n "CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7" | nc -4u -w1 192.168.1.57 2390
echo -n "CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7_46AD7EDE29FA7CB319F71F1EEDB78" | nc -4u -w1 192.168.1.57 2390
echo -n "CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7_46AD7EDE29FA7CB319F71F1EEDB78_6723127C14F6254B149C7115BFC76" | nc -4u -w1 192.168.1.57 2390
echo -n "CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7_46AD7EDE29FA7CB319F71F1EEDB78_6723127C14F6254B149C7115BFC76_199A88DF84A77684D148F8D9625B9" | nc -4u -w1 192.168.1.57 2390
echo -n "CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7_46AD7EDE29FA7CB319F71F1EEDB78_6723127C14F6254B149C7115BFC76_199A88DF84A77684D148F8D9625B9_3B4BD168F7A8D227EAB46FD442A63" | nc -4u -w1 192.168.1.57 2390
```

Here is the console output:

```
Received packet of size 29
From 192.168.1.165, port 49634
Contents:
CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411
Received packet of size 59
From 192.168.1.165, port 55833
Contents:
CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764
Received packet of size 89
From 192.168.1.165, port 59556
Contents:
CAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7
Received packet of size 119
From 192.168.1.165, port 59331
Contents:
CAFCAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7_46AD7EDE29FA7CB319F71F1B78
Received packet of size 149
From 192.168.1.165, port 51635
Contents:
CAFCAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7_46AD7EDE29FA7CB319F71F1EEDB78_6723127C14F6254B149C7115B6
Received packet of size 179
From 192.168.1.165, port 54811
Contents:
CAFCAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7_46AD7EDE29FA7CB319F71F1EEDB78_6723127C14F6254B149C7115BFC76_199A88DF84A77684D148F8D5B9
Received packet of size 209
From 192.168.1.165, port 49242
Contents:
CAFCAF99C4751FB1FD18F8A34BEBA411_E622319E55D4E871D2D787DDF5764_6CFE84A6C76C437714C2C329C86C7_46AD7EDE29FA7CB319F71F1EEDB78_6723127C14F6254B149C7115BFC76_199A88DF84A77684D148F8D9625B9_3B4BD168F7A8D227EAB46FD443
```

On the fourth message, it starts to repeat the first 3 characters and then truncate 3 characters near the end somewhere. On the fifth message, the 3 characters come back but the repeated first 3 are still there. I have no idea why this is happening. It seems that my buffer size is ok at 255 (I've tried 1024 as well). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on the TI E2E forum, https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/968/p/449876/1618051#1618051